# What is the easiest way to do this transformation in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table in this format, I want to calculate group-wise weightage average such that if there is null value for a particular value_KPI its weightage should be distributed equally to other KPIs from same group.

| Groups | KPIs | Weightages | value_KPI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | KP1 | 30% | 45 |
| G1 | KP2 | 30% |  |
| G1 | KP3 | 40% |  |
| G2 | KP4 | 30% | 34 |
| G2 | KP5 | 30% |  |
| G2 | KP6 | 20% | 90 |
| G2 | KP7 | 20% | 45 |

something like this:

| Groups | KPIs | Weightages | value_KPI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G1 | KP1 | 100% | 45 |
| G1 | KP2 |  |  |
| G1 | KP3 |  |  |
| G2 | KP4 | 40% | 34 |
| G2 | KP5 |  |  |
| G2 | KP6 | 30% | 90 |
| G2 | KP7 | 30% | 45 |

Please help me with python code to do this.

Comment: I dont have any nice pandas pattern solution but how about this:
1) calculate the total weight to be distributed `weights = df[df.value_KPI.isnull()].groupby(by='Groups')['value_KPI'].sum()`
2) for each group, calculate the uniform split by the total distributed weight divided by the number of elements in the group, to get the number of elements in each group you can groupby `Groups`  and sum non-null values
3) then, you can merge the results and simply add the distributed weight to the actual weight
I did not write a full code because Im certain theres a better way to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define a simple helper function:

```
def distribute(g):
    nans = g['value_KPI'].isna()
    g.loc[~nans, 'Weightages'] += g.loc[nans, 'Weightages'].sum()/sum(~nans)
    g.loc[nans, 'Weightages'] = 'NaN'
    return g
```

Now we apply it to each group after groupby

```
df.groupby(['Groups']).apply(distribute)
```

output:

```
    Groups    KPIs      Weightages    value_KPI
--  --------  ------  ------------  -----------
 0  G1        KP1              1             45
 1  G1        KP2            nan            nan
 2  G1        KP3            nan            nan
 3  G2        KP4              0.4           34
 4  G2        KP5            nan            nan
 5  G2        KP6              0.3           90
 6  G2        KP7              0.3           45
```